# How to change a MapView's main data

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet, r-mapview

I'm trying to use `observeEvent()` to change the Mapview's `x` argument to new data. I'd normally just use `clearShapes()` then `addPolygons()`, but need the `zcol` etc. arguments.

I'd like to do something similar to the following:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$DisplayMap <- renderLeaflet(
    mapview(first_data, zcol = coolCol, color = brewer.pal(12, "Set3") %>%
      addControl(actionButton("Next", ">"), position = "topright")
  )
  observeEvent(input$Next, {
    output$DisplayMap$x <- next_data  # This doesn't work
  })
}
```

I realise there's 2 issues at play (an interface to change the variable and a means to do so), and one of them probably needs React in some form or another

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I wish I could. This is behaviour I don't yet know how to achieve, so I'm not sure how to produce a reproducible example. I was thinking of snipping my half-implemented code, but I suspect that will produce some confusion and off-topic discussions as to other parts of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible to modify output like this (but indeed, it will be easier with MRE).

You should think about something like this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  my_data <- reactiveVal(data.frame(a = 1, b = 2))

  output$DisplayMap <- renderLeaflet(
    mapview(my_data()[[input$Next]], zcol = coolCol, color = brewer.pal(12, "Set3") %>%
      addControl(actionButton("Next", ">"), position = "topright")
  )
}
```

Assuming `input$Next` is a name of column which user can choose in GUI. This is just to show you an idea. Send MRE if you still need a help and I can edit this answer.

Comment: Ah, I see where you're going with that. Yes, that's what I was looking for, minus the `Next` value I need to get somehow. Would it be possible to edit your answer to include how I could add a hidden input value. That would make it complete. I hear such a thing is possible

Comment: I suppose the hidden input value is out of scope, so I've accepted this answer. The value DOES change, which is what I wanted